# What is the best subversion GUI based for someone who has never used subversion before?

Tags: windows, svn

I use visual studio 2005 so intergration is a must.

Thanks

Comment: I use VS and I use Tortoise, I prefer not to use a soft with integration  because of all the problems VS always have with sourcecontrol that is not Visual Safe model.

Comment: Until VS 2003 the real integrations had to use the checkout-checkin model. Since VS 2005 that is no longer true.. (Just look at AnkhSVN 2.0 that was designed for the new SCC VAPI instead of the old MSSCCI Api of old VS versions)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tortoise SVN and Ankh is what I prefer in VS2008.

Good luck!

Answer (score 10):

I really like TortoiseSVN.  It integrates well with the Windows shell and shields you from all the command line work.

Answer (score 4):

I think [Visual SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) is really good ...

Check out [Tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) as well.....

Comment: Visual SVN requires Tortoise. It uses Tortoise to handle the hard stuff.

Answer (score 2):

[AnkhSvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) and [tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) combined used to do the trick for me.

check tutorials online, or just go to the sites and read the wikis.

Answer (score 2):

Ankh is so bad. It doesn't react well to the actions you can perform within the solution explorer (like moving or deleting a file)

Buy VisualSVN, which is a bargain at $49 per seat.

Comment: haha.. or better yet, move to Git :) full integration is not always a good thing (or required) nothing wrong with opening a command prompt here and there hey? ;^)

Comment: nope, also keeps my commits nice and packaged, as I will more likely commit after completing a section of code with a command line. Plus, being able to segregate which files are commit, makes sure I get no jumble of files that should of been several commits

Comment: @Ric, Im with you on that, I dont get why people are so afraid of non integrated solutions

Comment: @BC: Which AnkhSVN did you look at? (I didn't see any messages on the AnkhSVN user lists and forum from you on the all new AnkhSVN 2.0 (Completely rewritten integration layer since 1.X))

Comment: @sambo: Maybe people aren't afraid but integration just makes everything easier. I fail to see how opening a command line and typing out a command is easier than right clicking on a file and selecting a context menu item.

Comment: @Bert maybe I was dealing with 1.x. But I guess I'm not the only one who thought it sucked.

Answer (score 2):

Props to Versions on the Mac! XCode is terrible (as in, I am broken and should have had this feature cut terrible) for SCM.

Answer (score 0):

[Syncro SVN Client](http://www.syncrosvnclient.com) comes bundled with [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com) but is also available as a standalone app.

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN or 2 plugins are available for Eclipse IDE: Subclipse or Subversive. I preffer Subversive.

Comment: the question is about Visual Studio, so you're off-topic here :)

Comment: Neither Title nor tags don't say that ;)

Comment: "I use visual studio 2005 so intergration is a must." :)

Answer (score -2):

Since, with SVN, you don't need to check out a file before you can start editing it, "intergration" with your IDE is, in fact, NOT a must.